# Multiple unrelated edits in a single topic

Tags: discussion, documentation

My use-case:

- I see interesting topic, so I dive in
- I see some little typo or something in one of the examples
- I click "Edit" button for the example and correct the typo
- I write a brief summary of my change
- I submit my changes for approval
- I see that I could add one more example
- I click "Add example" button and write the example
- Now, when I want to write a brief summary of my change, I see that there is already a summary from my previous change

This gives me a hint that when I am adding the example (my second change) I am in fact editing my first edit.

Is that right? If so, is that correct?

Those two edits doesn't have anything in common (apart from the topic), so I would not like to see one of the changes rejected due to the problems in the other. Also I don't really want to wait with my second change after the first one is approved...

Is there a way to commit multiple unrelated changes on one topic?